# How to read mysql data using panda filtering by a specific date

Tags: mysql, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a database stored in MySQL to python.

I understand how to connect and read the whole data, but I am having problem in how to just get the data from a specific date.
Like how to do SELECT * FROM country WHERE TIMESTAMP(date)= '2022-02-19' for example

I can get the whole table doing the following

```
engine = create_engine(mysql connection here)
tables = ['country','state','county']
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM '+tables[0], con=engine)

or 

df = pd.read_sql_table(tables[0], engine)
```

But now how I filter using a date? Let's say just bring everything from 2022-02-19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df = pd.read_sql(f"SELECT * FROM {tables[0]} WHERE date = '2022-02-19'", con=engine)
```